# Docker. Команда не запускается по ssh

Tags: docker

подскажите пожалуйста уже хз что делать и почему так.

Есть команда для запуска контейнера
`sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroiApks -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name=Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6 budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`

И так контейнер локально запускается.

Но мне нужно запускать контейнер удаленно(по ssh). И вот точно такую же команду(с прокидываением пароля) не принимает
`sudo sshpass -p "Пароль" ssh akupyrev@<некийIp>  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroidApks -e DEVICE=Samsung Galaxy S6 -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name="Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6" budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`

Ошибка — `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

Команду в `''` оборачивал - не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я точно не разобрался, но надо экранировать пробелы с помощью знака \(
т.е. заменить " " на "\ ").
Тогда пробелы сохраняются и строка не разлетается, вроде как так

Итоговая команда

`sudo sshpass -p "Пароль" ssh akupyrev@<некийIp>  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroidApks -e DEVICE="Samsung\ Galaxy\ S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name="Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6" budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`